# Sum of the series : $1 + 2+ 4 + 7 + 11 +\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I got a question which says

$$ 1 + \frac {2}{7} + \frac{4}{7^2} + \frac{7}{7^3} + \frac{11}{7^4} + \cdots$$

**I got the solution by dividing by $7$ and subtracting it from original sum. Repeated for two times.(Suggest me if any other better way of doing this)**.

However now i am interested in understanding the series 1,2,4,7,11,..... In which the difference of the numbers are consecutive natural numbers.

**How to find the sum of**

**$1+2+4+7+11+\cdots nterms$**

This is my first question in MSE. If there are some guidelines i need to follow, which i am not, please let me know.

Comment: Do you mean the sum of the first $n$ terms of $1+2+4+7+11+\cdots$? Also, what is the rule for the terms. You say "In which the difference of the numbers are continuous natural numbers" but this makes no sense to me.

Comment: As an infinite series it is divergent, but there are a few ways to regularize it. @AlexBecker Look at the consecutive differences; the terms are the triangular numbers shifted up one. (This might explain the remark you quote too).

Comment: @AlexBecker difference of the numbers(2-1(1),4-2(2),7-4(3),11-7(4),...) Thats exactly what i mentioned.. Yes i am looking for the solution for this number series..

Comment: @anon Thanks, I hadn't noticed that. Happy, again I'm unsure what you mean. You say "Yes i am looking for the solution for this number series" but series don't have solutions, they have sums, which can be either partial sums (the first $n$ terms) or the full sum, and in this case the full sum does not exist.

Comment: Will correct that. I want to find sum to nterms.

Comment: Ho to write a mathematical statement? I wrote it as 2/7^2. But edit made it proper. How to write the question in exact mathematical form, while posting the question?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Corrected. Thanks..

Comment: @Sandy, you're welcome.  Also, to find out how to "write mathematical statements," you might want to look at the answers to the question at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your series (without the denominators) is $$\sum_{i=1}^n 1+ \frac {i(i-1)}2=\sum_{i=1}^n 1+\frac {i^2}2 - \frac i2=n+\frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}-\frac{n(n+1)}4$$  This is an application of [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, the sum is not matching with the sum of series values. Ex: For n=1, the sum of the series you have given is 2 but the first term is 1. Pls clarify

Comment: It should be $i(i-1)/2$ on the LHS, and therefore a minus sign on the far rightmost term, to match the OP's terms

Comment: Thanks Ross, @anon. Changed the answer. Thank you

Comment: i/2 needs to be subtracted not added

Answer (score 6):

Let's first find the general form of the terms of the sum 
$1 + 2+ 4 + 7 + 11 +\ldots.$
The terms obey the recurrence
$a_n = a_{n-1} + n$, where $a_0 = 1.$
Using standard techniques we find 
$$a_n = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1) + 1.$$
These are basically the triangular numbers, as indicated by @anon in the comments.

The sum of the first $n+1$ terms can be found using 
Faulhaber's formula, as indicated by @RossMillikan, 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^n a_k 
&=& \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^n n^2 
    + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^n n
    + \sum_{k=0}^n 1 \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2} n(n+1) + n+1 \\
&=& \frac{1}{6}(n+1)(n^2+2n+6).
\end{eqnarray*}$$

The sum
$$\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{7^n}
= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n^2}{7^n}
    +  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{7^n}
    + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{7^n} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}$$
can be found by a standard trick.
Consider the geometric series
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$$
for $|x|<1$.
The last sum on the right hand side of (1) is just $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{7}} = 7/6$.
Now notice that for $m\in \mathbb{N}$
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^m x^n
&=& \left(x \frac{d}{dx}\right)^m \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^n \\
&=& \left(x \frac{d}{dx}\right)^m \frac{1}{1-x}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{7^n}
&=& \left[\frac{1}{2} \left(x \frac{d}{dx}\right)^2 \frac{1}{1-x}
+ \frac{1}{2} \left(x \frac{d}{dx}\right) \frac{1}{1-x}
+ \frac{1}{1-x} \right]_{x=1/7} \\
&=& \frac{1}{2}\frac{7}{27} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{7}{36} + \frac{7}{6} \\
&=& \frac{301}{216}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: @Sandy: The trick you use to sum $1 + \frac {2}{7} + \frac{4}{7^2} + \frac{7}{7^3} + \frac{11}{7^4} + \cdots$ is pretty good too!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: your series is simply $\sum\limits_n^{k} \frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n}{2}+1$

Comment: Thanks. Yup it was explained, it is one more than triangular numbers, and thats how we arrived at it. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: a very easy way to find it is by deriving it twice

Comment: What is with the infinity at the top limit? What is the argument of the sum? This is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Note that starting with your first element, $a_0=1$; to get to $a_1=2$ we sum $1$, to get to $a_2=4$, we sum $2$, to get to $a_3=7$, we sum $3$. So in general, we can say that

$$a_{n}=a_{n-1}+n$$

This is

$$
\begin{align}
2&=1+1 \\[8pt]
4& =2+2\\[8pt]
7&=4+3\\[8pt]
11& =7+4\\[8pt]
\cdots&=\cdots\\[8pt]
a_n&=a_{n-1}+n
\end{align}
$$

We can get several solutions to you problem, I will share $2$:

**Solution 1** Use the recursion to obtain a closed formula:

Since we know that $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+n$ we can write

$a_{n-1}=a_{n-2}+n-1$

so we get $$a_{n}=a_{n-2}+(n-1)+n$$

Repeating this process, we get that

$$a_{n}=a_{n-3}+(n-2)+(n-1)+n$$

$$a_{n}=a_{n-4}+(n-3)+(n-2)+(n-1)+n$$

$$a_{n}=a_{n-5}+(n-4)+(n-3)+(n-2)+(n-1)+n$$

...so in general we can say that

$$a_n=a_{n-k}+(n-k+1)+\cdots+n$$ for any $k$ a natural number.

(actually we should be proving the above by induction, but let it be)

So we can choose $k=n$, which means...

$$a_n=a_{n-n}+(n-n+1)+\cdots+n$$

$$a_n=a_0+(1+\cdots+n)$$

$$a_n=1+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

**Solution 2**

Starting from $$a_{n}=a_{n-1}+n$$ we use generating functions:

$$\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{a_n}} {x^n} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{a_{n - 1}}} {x^n} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  n {x^n}  \cr 
  & \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{a_n}} {x^n} = x\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{a_{n - 1}}} {x^{n - 1}} + x\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n{x^{n - 1}}}   \cr 
  & \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{a_n}} {x^n} - {a_0} = x\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{a_n}} {x^n} + x\frac{d}{{dx}}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{x^n}}   \cr 
  & A\left( x \right) - 1 = xA\left( x \right) + x\frac{d}{{dx}}\frac{1}{{1 - x}}  \cr 
  & A\left( x \right) - xA\left( x \right) = 1 + \frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^2}}}  \cr 
  & \left( {1 - x} \right)A\left( x \right) = 1 + \frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^2}}}  \cr 
  & A\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{{1 - x}} + \frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^3}}} \cr} $$

The generating sequence of $f(x)=\frac{1}{{1 - x}}$ is $a_n=1$, while the generating sequence of $g(x)=\frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^3}}}$ can be obtained by diferentiation of the first one:

$$\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{x^n}}  = \frac{1}{{1 - x}}  \cr 
  & \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {n{x^{n - 1}}}  = \frac{1}{{{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^2}}}  \cr 
  & \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {n\left( {n - 1} \right){x^{n - 2}}}  = \frac{2}{{{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^3}}}  \cr 
  & \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{n\left( {n - 1} \right)}}{2}{x^{n - 1}}}  = \frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^3}}}  \cr 
  & \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)}}{2}{x^n}}  = \frac{x}{{{{\left( {1 - x} \right)}^3}}} \cr} $$

so we finally get that

$$a_n=1+{\frac{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)}}{2}}$$

**ADD** I forgot to add the sum of the $a_n$s!

You need to evaluate

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k=n+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k=n+\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k\choose 2}$$

Using the binomial identity

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {k\choose l}={{n+1}\choose {l+1}}$$ we get

(you can find how to obtain it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Identities_involving_binomial_coefficients)

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k=n+{n+1\choose 3}$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k=n+\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{6}$$

which is what you wanted.

Comment: +1 - I'm surprised nobody else mentioned the binomial form, which is the canonical way (at least for a programmer) of handling explicit values for 'simplical' numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let T = 1 + 2/7 + 4/7^2 + 7/7^3 + ... ----> (1)

Then 
  T/7 =     1/7 + 2/7^2 + 4/7^3 + ... ----> (2)

Now, 
(2)-(1) => 6T/7 = 1 + 1/7 + 2/7^2 + 3/7^3 ----> (3)

Hence, (1/7)(6T/7) =  1/7 + 1/7^2 + 2/7^3 ----> (4)

So, (3)-(4)=> (1 - 1/7)(6T/7) = 1 + 0 + 1/7^2 + 1/7^3 + ...

```
       => (6/7)(6T/7) = 1 + (1/7^2 + 1/7^3 + .... infinity)

       => 36T/49 = 1 + (1/7^2)/(1 - 1/7)    [Formula = a/(1-r)]

       => 36T/49 = 1 + (1/49)/(6/7)

       => T = (49/36)(1 + (1/49)(7/6))

       => T = 49/36 + (49/36)(1/49)(7/6)

       => T = 49/36 + 7/216

       => T = (294 + 7)/216

       => T = 301/216
```

Comment: Regarding this problem, the question states: "I got the solution by dividing by 7 and subtracting it from original sum. Repeated for two times.(Suggest me if any other better way of doing this)."  This answer appears to suggest the same method.

Comment: Sorry, Din't read that thing!

Answer (score 0):

*(Edit: Upps, I see now this is essentially solution (2) of Peter Tamaroff's answer, but because it's much shorter I just leave it here)*

Your sequence can be separated into 2 sequences, where we add each pair:
$\begin{eqnarray}
 &1&2&4&7&11&16&\cdots & = a_k\\
\hline 
=&1&1&1&1&1&1&\cdots \\
+&0&1&3&6&10&15&\cdots \\
\hline \end{eqnarray}$

Then the partial sums are, beginning the index k at *1*:
$\begin{eqnarray}
 &1&3&7&14&25&41&\cdots &=&s_k\\
\hline 
=&1&2&3&4&5&6&\cdots &= &&=&k\\
+&0&1&4&10&20&35&\cdots &=&\binom{1+k}{3}&=&{(k+1)!\over 3! (k-2)!}\\
\hline 
=&1&3&7&14&25&41&\cdots &=&s_k&=& k+ {(k+1)!\over 3! (k-2)!}\\
\end{eqnarray}$

The last formula can be simplified to 
$$ s_k = k+ {(k+1)k(k-1) \over 6} = {6k+k^3-k\over 6} 
 = k \cdot {k^2+5\over 6}$$